# How can I split a multidemensional array evenly?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've found this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062864/populate-4-arrays-evenly-distributed-as-much-as-possible-from-top-to-bottom) that is quite similar to what I'm trying to achieve but I'd like to do it differently. I have an array of menu items which I've sorted out to be as a tree with the count of children.

```
$totalCount = 7; //defined in some previous code
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
        )
    )

)
```

I'd like to be able to sort this array into three arrays that are as even as possible and based on the number in count. The only way I can think of doing this is by a giant recursive loop. Is there a much simpler way of doing this that I'm overlooking like the for loop in the previous question?

*edit 1:*
Expected output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
            )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
            (
                [count] => 2
            )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate what `sort this array into three arrays that are as even as possible and based on the number in count` means with your expected output?

Comment: does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723059/split-array-into-a-specific-number-of-chuncks

Comment: @JRD: Added the desired output.

Comment: @devlin: It should sort the arrays into seperate arrays based on the count variable in the first child array.

Comment: `array_chunk()` is a nefty function